# Replace missing character (minus) in text font for use in siunitx with fontspec

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math

I'm forced to use a commercial ([Univers](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/)) font in my presentations, which obviously does not contain a dedicated `\minus` sign, which is called by [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx). (Though I'm not sure if it is `\minus` or something else.) So if I'm typing

```
\SI{-1984}{m^{-42}}
```

I don't get any minus displayed. Unfortunately I didn't found any free font with the same behaviour. But I hope you understand what I mean.

**How can I include the missing *minus sign* from another font into my text font to get [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx) to work properly?**

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Univers 45 Light} 
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\rmfamily,series=\normalfont}

\AtBeginDocument{
\usebeamerfont{normal text}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\rmfamily}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,fraction-function=\sfrac}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
The dash - is working. But the minus sign in \alert{siunitx} (e.g. \SI{-1984}{m^{-42}}) isn't, apart from when it is used in math-mode (e.g. $\SI{-1984}{m^{-42}}$). But in text I'd like to use my text font.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

giving me the output:

[image]

I don't have the problem with other fonts.

---

I tried various things, the first two gave me syntax errors:

```
\setmainfont[\minus="2212]{XITS Math}
```

or as I'm used to do for the math font:

```
\setmainfont[range={="2212}]{XITS Math}
```

And I found this code as well,

```
\newunicodechar{"2212}{{\fontspec{XITS Math}"2212}}
\newunicodechar{\minus}{{\fontspec{XITS Math}\minus}}
\newunicodechar{-}{{\fontspec{XITS Math}-}}
```

none of them working.

**Any more suggestions?**

---

The font I used does contain the character `\char"2013` but it doesn't contain `\char"2212` but it appears to me that this is the one called by [siunitx](/questions/tagged/siunitx) when the minus is typed.

egreg's suggestion

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2212}{\char"2013}
```

works for the unit

```
\SI{-1984}{m^{^^^^2212 42}})
```

but doesn't for the number, as `^^^^2212` it is an invalid  numeric character.

Comment: you can probably get away with an n-dash `--` U+2013

Comment: but how and where do I need to declare or use that?

Comment: simplest is just to use `--` instead of `-` in your text, which is all I was suggesting)

Comment: I get a misplaced sign token error: `Misplaced sign token '--1984'`

Comment: oh in siunitx, I was thinking of plain text, but anyway isn't that a minus sign at the start of the row with other math sybols here https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/pro-55-roman/glyphs.html?render=old

Comment: If you are willing to use U+2212 in the argument to `\SI` instead of the hyphen, you can do with `\newunicodechar{−}{\ifmmode–\else --\fi}`. There are two U+2212 in the code; explicitly, `\newunicodechar{^^^^2212}{\ifmmode ^^^^2212\else --\fi}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is [this font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/pro-45-light/glyphs.html) Yes there is a minus sign, the "minus" in plain text is working! So the question is, which minus is used by siunitx? And that one seems to be missing.

Comment: @egreg your suggestion is working for the unit part, e.g.: `\SI{-1984}{m^{^^^^2212 42}})` but for the number part is considered an invalid numeric character.

Comment: @thewaywewalk `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{...}{...}`?

Comment: @egreg Then the math font is used for the number :(

Comment: I can't test because I don't have your font, but maybe the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326159/36296 could also be applied here?

Comment: @samcarter looks promising, thanks for the link! However, the university finally realized that the used font was bulls*** and changed to Open Sans, so the problem does not persist anymore. Thanks anyway!