# Altering variable contents in expl3 (siunitx)

Tags: siunitx, expl3

**Context:**

I am still working on a solution for [Thin space between minus sign and number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326001/thin-space-between-minus-sign-and-number). After digging through the source code of `siunitx` I think I have to redefine `\c__siunitx_minus_tl`, but unfortunately my knowledge about `latex3` is close to non existent.

**Question**

How to redefine a command in `latex3`? I thought as the command was already present in the package, I could just `set` a new value

```
\tl_set:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl { + }
```

but this does not seem to have any influence. How to do this correctly?

**M(N)WE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{
   \tl_set:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl { + }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    math mode $\num{-42}$

    text mode \num{-42}

\end{document}
```

[The exact replacement symbol does not matter at this stage, my first goal to get the replacement to work]

Comment: I am not sure where the boundaries between `expl3` and `latex3` are, please suggest re-tagging if you think something else would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate issues here: how to redefine variable content any how to alter what you see with `siunitx`.

In terms of setting `expl3` variables, the normal approach is to use `\<thing>_set:Nn`. Here we have a token list, and if you put

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_show:N \c__siunitx_minus_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

after `\begin{document}` you will find it has been altered. I'll come back below to why that's not working in the output.

What you will notice here is that the variable is formally a constant (`\c_...`), so we should not attempt to set it. One can argue about whether this should be a constant, but as it is the conceptually more 'correct' way to deal with this situation is arguably to delete and recreate

```
\cs_undefine:N \c__siunitx_minus_tl
\tl_const:N \c__siunitx_minus_tl { + }
```

(The outcome is much the same, of course: ultimately we are dealing with a TeX macro.)

So why do you see no change? With the standard settings, `siunitx` uses math mode for printing numbers, and that means that `-` is passed through directly: `\c__siunitx_minus_tl` is not used. You will need to force text mode

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{mode = text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \c__siunitx_minus_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl { + }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
math mode $\num{-42}$

text mode \num{-42}
\end{document}
```

---

Of course, with `expl3` we don't generally encourage altering internal values from other code. Here, `siunitx` has been something of a 'test case' for `expl3` and when the current code was written the exact approach required in terms of interfaces was still being refined. I'd expect a v3 release of the package to have clearer interface set up, probably including a public name for `\c__siunitx_minus_tl`. (Work is ongoing on v3: tricky but I hope doable.)

Comment: Thank you so much - you're a Godsent! What a helpful, clear and informative answer! Seems like learning a bit `expl3` will open interesting possibilities.