# siunitx+fontspec+lualatex: use math font to fill one missing text glyph (minus sign)

Tags: fonts, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math, math-fonts

I'm re-asking an [unanswered question from 2015](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241386/replace-missing-character-minus-in-text-font-for-use-in-siunitx-with-fontspec). Here's what I'm using:

- [NOTO](https://fonts.google.com/noto) for normal, sans, and mono types via [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), aka `\setmainfont`
- [STIX Two](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts) for math via [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), aka `\setmathfont`
- [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) with `mode=match` to avoid `\qty` causing a grotesque switch to STIX Two in the middle of a sentence.

NOTO text fonts [lack a minus sign](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1013) by design, so `\qty{1}{\joule\per\meter}` results in a rectangle before `m`.

**Is there a way to substitute add a missing glyph (minus sign) to my serif font?**
unicode-math has a `range=` option to `\setmathfont`, but I can't pass that to `\setmainfont`.

---

Note: I'd like to use NOTO Sans Math for a consistent style, but I run into [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620779/noto-sans-maths-truetype-font-support-for-unicode-maths).

Comment: Have you tried something like `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{−}{\ensuremath{-}}` and `\renewcommand{\textminus}{\ensuremath{-}}`?

Comment: Can you add an example of your input: if I try to put something together, I do get the minus sign with the current `siunitx` release (2022-05-03 v3.1.1).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly. This code uses `\setmainfont`
and `\setmathfont`. It also specifies that `XITS Math` (but could be any other font) is to be used for `MINUS SIGN (U+2212)`, should it be missing from your main font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\newfontface{\xits}{XITS Math}
 
\iffontchar\font "2212\relax % do nothing if font has required glyph
\else
    \newunicodechar{^^^^2212}{{\xits −}} % use double braces to limit the scope
\fi

\begin{document}

\noindent HYPHEN-MINUS (U+002D) shown in \textbf{Noto Sans}: - \\
MINUS SIGN (U+2212) shown in \textbf{XITS Math} (Text mode) −

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works pretty well! I did the same for 2032 (prime). But it breaks for 00B1 (±); some error in `\newunicodechar{^^^^00B1}{\stixmath ±}`: "^^^^ needs four hex digits". Using `^^B1` didn't work either. Any idea?

Comment: Try lowercase b … That said, both ′ and ± seem to be part of Noto Sans already. Note: I also modified my code above slightly (added double braces to limit the scope of the font).